# Lock data types of few columns using xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I want to lock few of the columns in my dataframe to allow numbers only (no characters).

I tried the below code and it works perfectly fine when I manually input the values (means it does not allow me to input characters) but when I try to copy and paste the character, it doesn't stop me to do so.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                   'Data2': [11, 21, 31, 21, 15, 31, 45]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_filter.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', )

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

worksheet.data_validation('A2:B8', {'validate': 'custom',
                                  'value': '=ISNUMBER(A2:A8)'})

writer.save()
```

Comment: Same comment as the previous question: figure out how to do it in Excel and then apply that to XlsxWriter. However, in this case I don't think it is possible in Excel to prevent a user from pasting over a data validation without using VBA. See this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/870926/restrict-paste-into-dropdown-cells-in-excel